# Setting bits on an integer and displaying it on the page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set 4 bits on an integer based on whether a checkbox is checked. I'm new with JavaScript so pardon my bad code. I searched how to set bits and found the function `setBit`. It's clear what it does, however when I print out the result `n`, I keep on getting 0. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I can't quite figure out what it is.

Any help is welcomed.

```js
function setBit(number, bitPosition) {
  return number |= 1 << bitPosition;
}

function checkCheckbox() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  var two = document.getElementById("two");
  var three = document.getElementById("three");
  var four = document.getElementById("four");
  var n = 0

  if (one.checked == true) {
    setBit(n, 0)
  }

  if (two.checked == true) {
    setBit(n, 1)
  }

  if (three.checked == true) {
    setBit(n, 2)
  }

  if (four.checked == true) {
    setBit(n, 3)
  }

  return document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = n;

}
```

```html
<h2>Numbers</h2>
<br>
<p>
  1? <input type="checkbox" id="one" value="1"><br>
  2? <input type="checkbox" id="two" value="2"><br>
  3? <input type="checkbox" id="three" value="3"><br>
  4? <input type="checkbox" id="four" value="4">
</p>
<br> <br>
<button onclick="checkCheckbox()">Submit</button> <br>

<h3 style="color:green" id="out"></h3>
```

Comment: `setBit` doesn't mutate the actual passed number, it returns the number with the bit set so instead of `setBit(n, <number>)` you have to do it like this `n = setBit(n, <number>)`

Comment: As an unrelated note, you don't need to compare `one.checked == true`. The `.checked` property is already a boolean.